# mountPath overrides the rest of the files in that same folder

Tags: kubernetes

I have a volume with a secret called config-volume. I want to have that file in the /home/code/config folder, which is where the rest of the configuration files are. For that, I mount it as this:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volumes
  - mountPath: /home/code/config
```

The issue is that, after deploying, in the /home/code/config I only have the secret file and the rest of them are gone

So the /home/code/config is an existing folder (not empty), I suspect that the volumeMount overwrites the folder.

Is there a way that this can be done without overwriting everything?

Comment: You have to use the hidden subPath value, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415913/whats-the-best-way-to-share-mount-one-file-into-a-pod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes Secrets are mounted as a directory, with [each key as a file](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) in that directory. So in your case, the `config-volumes` secret is mounted to `/home/code/config`, shadowing whatever that directory was before.

You could specify your volume mount as:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volumes
  - mountPath: /home/code/config/config-volumes
```

which would provide a `config-volumes` directory inside the `config` directory with files for your secret's keys inside.

Answer (score 20):

You can do the following, taken from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44815#issuecomment-297077509)

```
containers:
- volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volumes
    mountPath: /home/code/config
    subPath: config
volumes:
- name: config-volumes
  configMap:
    name: my-config
```

Suggested that your `ConfigMap`is called *my-config* and that you have a key *config* in it.