# How to mount a single file in container in kubernetes/docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, host, mount

I have a single file which I want to mount in the container. The file is present in `conf` folder which also contains other file but the file I only want to mount is `helper.conf`. Doing this in docker:

```
docker run -it -v /path/to/dir/:/path/inside/container --name mycontainer dockerimage
```

Doing this throws below error:

> Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check
>   if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

To resolve this, I created another folder with name `config` inside `conf` and used below line:

```
docker run -it -v /path/to/dir/config:/path/inside/container --name mycontainer dockerimage
```

This works perfectly fine. Same is happening with `kubernetes`. Is it not possible to just mount a single file from a directory where other files are also present. Am I using wrong keywords for this.?

How can I resolve in Kubernetes?

Comment: I think what you can do is to make a configmap for the file and mount that into the pod - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404857/9705485

Comment: @RyanDawson Agree but if we update that file, then we will have to run the command again to make the changes and then redeploy it. Is that true.?

Comment: Yes. Are you running the cluster on the local machine (e.g. minikube)? If so I think you're right that you can only mount directory (e.g. using hostPath https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2#issuecomment-406279202).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has been provided by @[Ryan Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9705485/ryan-dawson).

The best way to mount a single file in container (in Kubernetes) would be to use ConfigMap:

> ConfigMaps allow you to decouple configuration artifacts from image
>   content to keep containerized applications portable.

ConfigMap can be used in this case to create a resource which will allow us to keep the configuration separate from the container image. As the configuration is a set of key-value pairs, it will allow to expose it as an environment variable that can be put inside the container or a volume. After creating ConfigMap, you will have to create a pod where you  specify a ConfigMap it can consume to get necessary values. 
In your situation, as [Joel B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316857/joel-b) and [Tommy Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490986/tommy-nguyen) specified in this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415913/whats-the-best-way-to-share-mount-one-file-into-a-pod/43404857#43404857) :

> You could use subPath like this to mount single file into existing directory.