# Playframework: `reference.conf` not loaded in Kubernetes (Openshift)

Tags: playframework, kubernetes, openshift

I have a strange behaviour on Kubernetes (Openshift).

It looks like the configuration file `reference.conf` is not loaded when starting the Application.

The same image works when used with plain Docker.

When I copy the properties to `application.conf` it works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I made a mistake in mounting a file with *Kubernetes*.

My config looked like:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ${COMPONENT_NAME}-config-volume
          mountPath: /${COMPONENT_NAME}/conf
```

This overwrote the whole *configuration* directory, instead just the files.

The correct one is:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ${COMPONENT_NAME}-config-volume
          mountPath: /${COMPONENT_NAME}/conf/application.conf
          subPath: "application.conf"
```

This I got from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404857/2750966