# How to mount a specific file within a pod folder containing multiple files & folders in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I am trying to mount a specific file from a folder containing multiple files & folders of a kubernetes pod into the host machine's path as a backup.

I am using PersistentVolumeClaim as a volume and am able to mount the complete folder instead of that specific file. And this folder is accessible via the host machine's path.

Following are my deployment, PVC and PV files.

**Deployment file:**

```
containers:
- name: katana-db
  image: postgres:10.4
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  envFrom:
  - configMapRef:
      name: war-config
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    name: katana-db
volumes:
- name: katana-db
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: katana-db-volume-claim
```

**Persistent Volume Claim:**

```
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: katana-db-volume-claim
  namespace: {{ $.Values.namespace }}
  creationTimestamp: null
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: "katana-db-volume"
---
```

**Persistent Volume:**

```
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: katana-db-volume
  namespace: {{ $.Values.namespace }}
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /mnt/k8sMount/data/local-persist/data/warrior/katana-db
    server: 167.xx.xx.xx
---
```

I want to mount the file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/config.ini" instead of the complete folder "/var/lib/postgresql/data" that I mentioned in the deployment file so that I can have a backup of this file in my host machine.

I found "hostpath" volume but it seems to be unfit for production as suggested by kubernetes forums.

Please let me know the volume that I can use to mount a specific file from a folder within a Pod so that I can access it via the host machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415913/whats-the-best-way-to-share-mount-one-file-into-a-pod

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to share/mount one file into a pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415913/whats-the-best-way-to-share-mount-one-file-into-a-pod)

Comment: The mounted file (config.ini) is going to be updated in the Pod so I need the updated file to be available in the host machine. Please let me know the changes that I need to add, to make the file available in the host machine

Comment: To understand correctly, you want to mount the file into specific location and avoid overwriting the folders/files that are already there?

Comment: I want to mount a file from a specific location in the host machine into a pod's location. The pod will overwrite this file and I need the updated file to be available from the host machine path.

Comment: The application overwrites a specific file (config.ini) present in Pod's folder containing multiple files. I just want to backup this file (config.ini) from the host machine.

Comment: Having a mounted file is different than having a copy of that file. What is your desired state here? Does it has to be on the host? Can it be mounted on the NFS server?

Comment: I need the copy of the file to be available on host. Yes it can be mounted on NFS and am already using nfs in the PV that I mentioned in the query but not sure how I can do it for a file alone

Comment: I think I understand it now, I will prepare an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have the file `mounted` to the host file system than the `hostPath` is the the way to but the main drawback of using it is that when your pod will be terminated it might be scheduled into different node. In that case the data would be lost. You could workaround this with setting appropriate label to the node if that is so important.

To mount a file instead of directory you can use `subPath` like in this example:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test
      mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/config.ini
      subPath: config.ini
```

You need to use `mountPath` with directory and filename and `subPath` field with file name as well.

Instead of  `hostPath` you could use your [NFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) server and if you must have it on the host you can mount the `nfs` into it. With this you can be sure that the contents of this volume are preserved.

And then just mount the server like in [this example](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/kubernetes/storage/use-nfs-volumes):

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test
      mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/config.ini
      subPath: config.ini

  volumes:
    - name: nfs-volume
      nfs: 
        server: nfs.example.com # Change this to your NFS server
        path: /data # Change it to something relevant for your case
```

Let me know if it helps.