# Why am I getting CrashLoopBackOff from my docker image and the logs don't say what is wrong?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I created an image with Docker using this `Dockerfile` and I pushed it to docker-hub.

```
FROM gcc AS builder
RUN mkdir -p /opt
COPY ./generate-tpch-dbgen.sh /opt/generate-tpch-dbgen.sh
WORKDIR /opt
RUN chmod +x /opt/generate-tpch-dbgen.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/opt/generate-tpch-dbgen.sh"]
```

and this is the `generate-tpch-dbgen.sh` script that I am running inside the image.

```
#!/bin/sh

# download
git clone https://github.com/electrum/tpch-dbgen.git

# replace variables
cd tpch-dbgen
sed -i '/CC      =/c\CC=gcc' makefile.suite
sed -i '/DATABASE=/c\DATABASE=INFORMIX' makefile.suite
sed -i '/MACHINE =/c\MACHINE=LINUX' makefile.suite
sed -i '/WORKLOAD =/c\WORKLOAD=TPCH' makefile.suite

# compile
make -f makefile.suite

# run the tpch-dbgen to generate data with database factor of 0.1GB
mkdir data && cd data
cp ../dbgen . && cp ../dists.dss .
./dbgen -f -s 0.1
ls -l

# create the datarate.txt file
mkdir -p /tmp
echo "1000000000" > /tmp/datarate.txt
```

Then I am creating a pod from a deployment object using Kubernetes (minikube). I want this image to be available and not terminate because I will share the directory `/opt/tpch-dbgen/data` from this image that is generated by the script `/opt/generate-tpch-dbgen.sh`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tpch-dbgen-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: tpch-dbgen
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: tpch-dbgen
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tpch-dbgen
        image: felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I am getting the `CrashLoopBackOff` error on the pod. But the log says that my files are there and I cannot see any other relevant error to fix. I suppose that there is a problem with my deployment file, but the logs don't give any hint to me, or I don't know where to look. What is wrong with my deployment?

```
felipe@cow-11:~/workspace-scala/explore-flink$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
tpch-dbgen-deployment-57587d8748-gd4xs   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          7m34s
felipe@cow-11:~/workspace-scala/explore-flink$ kubectl describe pods tpch-dbgen-deployment-57587d8748-gd4xs
Name:         tpch-dbgen-deployment-57587d8748-gd4xs
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.99.100
Start Time:   Wed, 23 Sep 2020 09:38:11 +0200
Labels:       component=tpch-dbgen
              pod-template-hash=57587d8748
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/tpch-dbgen-deployment-57587d8748
Containers:
  tpch-dbgen:
    Container ID:  docker://3ddf1b5306707f4ba60a35f08306f1a621a744e5ce08c7e5806594ba80865fba
    Image:         felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen@sha256:079c7f009a8cb93830cb11ff71bdba122795b7c8750e65f308dc43174252f71a
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
    Args:
      ls ; pwd ; ./generate-tpch-dbgen.sh ; ls
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 23 Sep 2020 09:45:10 +0200
      Finished:     Wed, 23 Sep 2020 09:45:20 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  6
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7snfd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-7snfd:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7snfd
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m43s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/tpch-dbgen-deployment-57587d8748-gd4xs to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     7m40s                   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen" in 1.732811715s
  Normal   Pulled     7m24s                   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen" in 1.522490498s
  Normal   Pulled     6m58s                   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen" in 1.570829385s
  Normal   Created    6m23s (x4 over 7m40s)   kubelet, minikube  Created container tpch-dbgen
  Normal   Pulled     6m23s                   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen" in 3.077114721s
  Normal   Started    6m22s (x4 over 7m40s)   kubelet, minikube  Started container tpch-dbgen
  Normal   Pulling    5m23s (x5 over 7m42s)   kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen"
  Normal   Pulled     5m21s                   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "felipeogutierrez/tpch-dbgen" in 1.834155671s
  Warning  BackOff    2m33s (x19 over 7m13s)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
felipe@cow-11:~/workspace-scala/explore-flink$ kubectl logs tpch-dbgen-deployment-57587d8748-gd4xs
Cloning into 'tpch-dbgen'...
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o build.o build.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o driver.o driver.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o bm_utils.o bm_utils.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o rnd.o rnd.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o print.o print.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o load_stub.o load_stub.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o bcd2.o bcd2.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o speed_seed.o speed_seed.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o text.o text.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o permute.o permute.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o rng64.o rng64.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O -o dbgen build.o driver.o bm_utils.o rnd.o print.o load_stub.o bcd2.o speed_seed.o text.o permute.o rng64.o -lm
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o qgen.o qgen.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o varsub.o varsub.c
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DINFORMIX -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O -o qgen build.o bm_utils.o qgen.o rnd.o varsub.o text.o bcd2.o permute.o speed_seed.o rng64.o -lm
TPC-H Population Generator (Version 2.14.0)
Copyright Transaction Processing Performance Council 1994 - 2010
total 105448
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2426114 Sep 23 07:45 customer.tbl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   116600 Sep 23 07:45 dbgen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    11815 Sep 23 07:45 dists.dss
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 74246996 Sep 23 07:45 lineitem.tbl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2224 Sep 23 07:45 nation.tbl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16893122 Sep 23 07:45 orders.tbl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2391090 Sep 23 07:45 part.tbl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11728193 Sep 23 07:45 partsupp.tbl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      389 Sep 23 07:45 region.tbl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   139625 Sep 23 07:45 supplier.tbl
```

Comment: "Directory" isn't really a Kubernetes concept.  Your earlier question discussed using a volume of some sort for this; that's the right approach, and you don't need to keep the loader pod running in order to use the volume contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container in your pod exited with status `0` which means that the command in your container has successfully finished. You have not specified any `restartPolicy` for your container so the default is `Always`. Since your container finished - it will be restarted due to it's restart policy (actually you cannot even change that when using a deployment - it is always `Always`.

The deployment should be used when you have some long running processes and you want to make sure that all instances of those processees are up and can be rolled out to new versions if needed.

For one hit processes that do something and then quit - you might better use [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

Comment: but I don't want to do "one hit" process. I want that this process stays up so I can share the directory that I create on it with another pods.

Comment: I guess I got it. First I had to add this line `sleep infinity & wait` in the end of my script to make the process not terminate. Second, I am using a Job as you said, and with `restartPolicy: OnFailure`.