# How Can I Copy File to Minikube Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I want to copy a text file to a pod on minikube. But I get the timeout error[image].

```
scp -r /Users/joe/Downloads/Archive/data.txt  docker@192.168.49.2:/home/docker
```

I got the ip address (192.168.49.2) with:

```
minikube ip
```

Eventually I would like that the file appear on the persistentVolumeClaim/persistentVolume (that will be great!!)

The yaml for the PersistentVolume is:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

The yaml for the PersistentVolumeClaim is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 512Mi
```

The yaml for the pod is:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pvc-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 3600; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/storage"
      name: my-storage
  volumes:
  - name: my-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-pvc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Eventually I would like that the file appear on the persistentVolumeClaim/persistentVolume.**

You can achieve that with mounting the host directory into the guest using `minikube mount` [command](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/):

```sh
minikube mount <source directory>:<target directory>
```

Whereas the the `<source directory>` is the host directory and `<target directory>` is the guest/minikube directory.

And then use that `<target directory>` and create pv with `hostPath`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "<target-directory"
```

Depending also driver, some of them have built-in host folder sharing. You can check them [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts).

If you need to mount only part of the volume, in your case a single file, you can use `subPath` to specify the part that must be mounted. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415913/whats-the-best-way-to-share-mount-one-file-into-a-pod) answer explains it well.